# How to determine what should be a function

Tags: python, function

I am new to programming and am teaching myself the subject during my free time.

One thing I am having trouble with right now is writing programs that go beyond, say, 75 or so lines. I am having trouble determining when to make something a function to make my program more readable. I tend to get a little lost in my own programs, and I also feel like they aren't very "efficient" when I look at them.

Below is an example of a still incomplete random word game I made. It is not finished b/c I still need to account for the fact that the user could provide invalid inputs. As it stands now that would crash the program. I am most concerned with my "game" function specifically and would like to know if there is a way I could divide it up or perhaps do something else to make it more readable or "better."

Below is the code to my program:

```
#random_game
import random

def letter_guess():
    #function to prompt for and return user guess
    guess= input("Guess a letter: ").lower()
    return guess

def game(word):
    guess_count=0
    word_list=list(word)
    #formula to deternime number of guesses
    total_tries=len(word)+len(word)//2+1
    print("the word is",len(word),"characters long. "\
          "You have",total_tries,"guesses")
    template=["__" for i in range(len(word_list))]  
    print (template)

    while guess_count < total_tries and word_list != template:
        #one guess per iteration
        guess=letter_guess()                

        for i,v in enumerate(word_list):
            if guess == v:
       #adding 1 b/c I don't want a position 0.
                print("letter found at position",i+1)       
                template[i]=v
        if guess not in word_list:
            print("letter not in word.\n")
        print(template)
        guess_count+=1
    if word_list==template:
        print("you won!\n")
    else:
        print("You lose! The word was",word,"\n")

def main():
    #my initial list of words
    database=["banana","cat","superman","mississippi","sleep","volcano",\
              "school","spongebob","zebra","fish","keyboard","building",\
              "python","computer","lizard","wonderful","flower","japan"]
    while True:
        index=random.randint(0,len(database)-1)
        #get the answer to the game based on a random word selected from database
        word=database[index]
        game(word)
        again=input("would you like to play again?(yes/no) ")
        if again =="no":
            print("Thanks for playing my extremely poorly designed game!")
            break
        else:
            print("next game...\n")
main()
```

I can tell that my code (especially the "game" function) looks sloppy and not as well put together as the code I see other users here post.

I am trying to avoid bad practices, and while I can look up the answers to 95% of my questions online already, I haven't been able to find much material in this area. Also please let me know if my question is not appropriate for this website. Thank you.

Comment: This question may be better suited to [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Lumberjack Yes, go for codereview. Your question is good, codereview shall give you the hints. Just keep trying, questioning, working through tutorials and trying your own experiments and you will master it.

Comment: Personally I don't think you have too much to be concerned about.You could probably even remove `letter_guess` as a function. Maybe space your code out a little more. You could try running your code through an online pep-8 checker and see what it points out.  For such a small program don't worry so much about breaking it into functions as it only creates indirection when you try to read it later.

Comment: I was not familiar with code review. That is good to know for these types of questions. Thanks. A moderator can "remove" my question if necessary.

Comment: You should probably take this to our [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that there is no rule that you MUST create a function to make your code more readable and efficient. I think where/when to create a function is depending on preference.

Anyway, I look at your code, and if you want to make your code more concise, (what I would do if I were you) is that I will create a function that take care of the looping part (see below).

```
while guess_count < total_tries and word_list != template:
    #one guess per iteration
    guess=letter_guess()                

    for i,v in enumerate(word_list):
        if guess == v:
   #adding 1 b/c I don't want a position 0.
            print("letter found at position",i+1)       
            template[i]=v
    if guess not in word_list:
        print("letter not in word.\n")
    print(template)
    guess_count+=1
```

Hope my suggestion helps.

Keep it up !

Answer (score 2):

This is subjective so probably not entirely appropriate for SO, but my two cents: Imagine that you're organizing a group of friends to perform whatever task your program does.

You want to divide up chunks of work and delegate those to different people so that everyone works together to get the job done. So say, "Jack, you do this part. Linda, you take care of that. Vijay, you work on this."

Then each friend becomes a function (or as your experience grows, maybe a class definition).